# Substitute based product In Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, product-attribute, custom-options, products

I am developing a medicine based eCommerce site on Magento, I want to display the substitute based product in product page just like in [1mg](https://www.1mg.com/drugs-substitutes/calpol-500mg-tablet-69656) and [NetMeds](http://www.netmeds.com/prescriptions/calpol/syrup-120mg-60ml). Can anyone please help to find the Magento extension for this or any existing solution.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the sites that you have linked to, I would suggest using the Upsells feature - when editing a product, click "upsells" on the left and select the products you want to feature as substitutes. Then, modify the upsells block template in your theme to display the text as you require.

By default, this file should app/design/frontend/[your_package]/[your_theme]/catalog/product/list/upsell.phtml - if it's not there then copy it down from base/default

You will likely want to at least change the text "You may also be interested in the following product(s)" to "Available substitutes"

**NOTE: avoid editing base default** as it will be lost if you ever upgrade magento (and you should never edit core files anyway for this reason)